# How to restrict sliding area in "android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout"

Tags: android

I am implementing sliding panel using `-android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout`

Since `Slidingpanel` slides the RIGHT panel on swipe (left/right). I want to give another swipe `action(fling)` in the RIGHT panel as well. How can I do this? Can i restrict the swipe area for Slider to the left most part of `View` (like in `NavigationDrawer`).